# Copy right of style files, e.g. Cambridge University Press's

Tags: document-classes, copyright

Just started using LaTeX so pardon my ignorance here. I was wondering whether style files created for example by Cambridge University Press are free to be used for commercial purposes (a book, respectively) or whether you need a special permission of the publisher? Any help is very much appreciated, preferable with link to the source that provides this information :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: A style or class file will have a license statement accompanying it. It's impossible to tell without a pointer.

Answer (score 10):

The [classes of the Cambridge University Press](http://authornet.cambridge.org/information/productionguide/laTex_files/) include these lines at the beginning of the file:

```
%% This software may only be used in the preparation of journal articles
%% or books or parts of books to be published by Cambridge University Press.
%% Any other use constitutes an infringement of copyright.
```

So I'm afraid you can't use them for other purposes, except with special permission of the copyright holder.

Comment: Hi! Thanx so much for your quick answer! I have downloaded all the LaTeX macros, but I am swimming a bit in this sea of documents, which function is not always clear to me. I also cannot spot copy right notes on the Tex documents, nor did I find an extra document with notes on copy right. Where did you find this note precicely? Sorry for my slowlyness and thanx again for your support! Anja

Comment: @Anja Take for example [`EngC.zip`](http://authornet.cambridge.org/information/productionguide/laTex_files/downloads/EngC.zip): It contains the actual class file `EngC.cls`, which is responsible for the layout and contains the above copyright notice (ll. 22-24). The other files included in the archive are an example document (`EngCguide.tex`) that shows you how to use the documentclass and serves as a documentation, and various packages (extension `.sty`). The other archives follow a similar structure. So the important file that also contains the copyright notice is the `.cls` file.

Answer (score 9):

A lot of packages have the licence statement:

```
%% This package may be distributed under the terms of the LaTeX Project
%% Public License, as described in lppl.txt in the base LaTeX distribution.
%% Either version 1.0 or, at your option, any later version.
```

the LPPL can be read [here](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt) or simply run `texdoc LPPL`

Special packages, which are not on CTAN may have other licence statements with some restrictions. However, I cannot see a problem when using packages from publishers for writing a manuscript.

Comment: Hi! Thank you as well! SO you mean style files that contain the above comment are free for commercial use? If I was to write a study book for example. WHat does CTAN mean? SOrry, I am obviously really new here :-) THanx!

Comment: I found out what CTAN is :-)